# What Notable Differences are there between Railo, Open Bluedragon, and Adobe Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo, openbd, cfml

An attempt to capture ***notable*** differences between implementations:

1. [Adobe ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/)
2. [Railo](http://www.getrailo.com/)
3. [Open Bluedragon](http://www.openbluedragon.org/)

(I'm aware of [Smith](http://www.smithproject.org/), but don't believe it's still active).

Include CFML ***and*** platform differences - syntax, feature, and extensibility.

Note, this is not something I've not seen anywhere else, but maybe I'm just not searching correctly. So links to that end would count too.

**Update**

Here's my definition of **notable** in this context: something that simplifies solving a difficult problem. For example, Railo offers the `<cfvideo>` tag, which transcodes video - a non trivial task.

Something I would suggest is *not notable*: the Railo function [ListAvg](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-1-Functions:ListAvg)().

Comment: "notable" is really subjective category. Someone may find ListAvg 100x times useful than cfvideo.

Comment: @Sergii - do you find ListAvg() notable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marking as a community wiki.

**Overview**

- [Blog post comparing of ColdFusion and Railo](http://www.cfmldeveloper.com/page.cfm/coldfusion-vs-railo-1) - comments are just as interesting.

Aggregation of items I've called "notable":

**Open Bluedragon**

1. [Web based line debugger](http://www.openbluedragon.org/manual/?/plugin_debugger): Adobe Eclipse based is finicky.
2. [Memcached intregration](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=open+bluedragon+memcached): Adobe ehcache solution works well, but memcached still appears to have better failover and sharding. In fact, sharding appears to only be available in Adobe with Terracotta or rolling your own.
3. [Runs on Google App Engine](http://groups.google.com/group/openbd)

**Railo**

1. [`<cfvideo>`](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/railo-3-0-released-features-part-iii-multimedia): video transcoding, pay feature, but low cost, free option is [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), but that has legal question marks
2. [`cluster` scope](http://corfield.org/entry/Railo_Cluster_Scope): interesting way of solving messaging between servers, pay feature.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you're going to get to a complete answer will be: http://cfml-engines.info/, which is a work in progress and doesn't have all of the information you're looking for. It's just too open-ended of a question.

Comment: The intention is not capture every nit, but rather notable differences. For instance, I see Railo offers a cluster scope in the enterprise version, which I don't believe has an equivalent in other engines. So understand the CFML standardization committee is effectively caput, but I think it's still possible to tease out some interesting differences.

Comment: @orangepips - Definitely nice information to have. But even at a high level, it is still a pretty broad question. I would be interested to see what people come up with.

Comment: @Leigh, agreed it's broad, but one that near as I can tell has been approached only on a point by point basis. So I think there's the possibility of identifying more general differences, but maybe I'm mistaken in thinking they exist.

Comment: @orangepips - Yes, a high level list would be useful. But unfortunately, I suspect it does not exist yet. Though I would be happy to be proven wrong ;)

Comment: @Leigh - the intent is to capture those high level items here.

Comment: @Henry: it was working when I posted it. No idea why it's down now.

Comment: Doh! Had some server problems the other day, but thought I'd fixed them all. Going to http://cfml-engines.info/wiki works, and I'll go fix the 403 now.

Comment: Ok, should be working now. (If anyone spots any more errors please let me know.)

Comment: Also, my current plans are both to describe every different feature in detail, as well as providing practical summaries of the differences (what you need to know to work across the engines).

Eventually, it'd be great to allow the user to define what is notable based on what they use (e.g. "show me how <List functionality> differs" or "what are the <multimedia> options", and so on).


Annoyingly, I wont be able to get back on this for at least a couple of months, probably longer - but once I do, hopefully it will be able to provide the information people are after.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the differences in the syntax of executing let's say a stored procedure, and any differences in the results coming back.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to search A LOT. Both "alternative" engines have *official* wikis with articles specifically describing the compatibility questions:

- http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Dashboard#CFML_Documentation
- http://wiki.openbluedragon.org/wiki/index.php/Category:Compatibility

Comment: So I'd consider the memcached support of Open Blugdragon notable. Wouldn't you? But again, rather than a place where it's possible to see these interesting differences, and perhaps some narrative to go with them, it's laundry lists with little explanation (in fact memcached hasn't even been written on their wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Another place to look for the latest details on OpenBD:
http://www.openbluedragon.org/manual

That documentation is pulled straight from the codebase so it's always up to date. (This is another way of saying the OpenBD wiki may not necessarily be the latest and greatest.)

Comment: So I'd say the web based debugger is a notable difference: http://www.openbluedragon.org/manual/?/plugin_debugger. Particularly since I find Adobe ColdFusion + Eclipse line debugger to be finicky. As a steering committee member, any other interesting areas you'd highlight?