# What could break when migrating from Adobe ColdFusion to an alternative CFML engine?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, bluedragon

We are currently using Adobe ColdFusion 9 for a rather large application. We are thinking about moving to Railo or Blue Dragon.

What problems will we run into?

- Will it require a large amount of refactoring or will most CFML code just work on the new system?
- Do alternative engines provide support for most all official tags, or are they more limited?
- In short, how divergent are these alternatives from the official language?
- Is there anything we can do to make this process less painful (like upgrading to CF11 first or removing/avoiding certain features)?

My question is similar to [What Notable Differences are there between Railo, Open Bluedragon, and Adobe Coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480205/what-notable-differences-are-there-between-railo-open-bluedragon-and-adobe-col), but while that is concerned with practical differences I'm asking more specifically about practicality of transition/implementation.

Comment: make sure to explicitly scope your URL and FORM vars.  That'll be one nag when pulling your code over.  You can turn it off in RAILO (I believe), but you should be doing this out of habit anyways.

Comment: With regards Adobe's _"very uncertain future with them"_ here's their roadmap going up to 2022: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/assets/content/roadmap/ColdFusion%20RoadMap.pdf

Comment: If you're going to use Railo you can create a mapping in the server admin and then click on compile to find any unsupported tags you're using (cfform, cfpod, etc). That will help point out some issues.

Comment: Duncan I can show you my blog's roadmap to 2022 if you like. But it'd be meaningless given it'd not be legally binding and I could reserve the right to change it whenever I like. A case in point with Adobe they on their roadmap only about 18 months ago that CF11 would be released in 2013, and CF12 in 2014. That doesn't reflect reality, does it?

Comment: Do *not* consider BlueDragon. It is barely a CFML engine any more, and they make no attempt any more to stay compatible with the other engines. IMO Railo is the only viable CFML engine available these days.

Comment: Adam, can you expand upon this, or do you know of a good external resource that does?  Most of my knowledge of Blue Dragon is many years old.  Thanks.

Comment: For Railo there is a good guide here: https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Language_And_Syntax_Differences

Comment: "Bill the Lizard", I know you're a grand poobah here, but you're out of line closing this. I might not fit your perceived model of good question, but in our community it *is* a good question, and will get good, helpful answers. Looking at your profile, you do not have the expertise to judge what is or is not  good question in the context of ColdFusion, CFML or Railo, so please just let us look after it. As you're a moderator you can just reopen this question without us needing to vote, so can you please just do so? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple good answers here and I appreciate the advice given in them.  When I asked this question I was looking for something a little more specific, so now that I've had the chance to really play around with migrating our app to Railo I thought I should come back and list out the issues we've run into and, just as importantly, the severity and workarounds.  Hopefully this will help others considering making the jump:

1. **cfMessageBox:**
   cfMessageBox is not a supported tag in Railo.  The best solution we've come up with is to create a new custom tag called MessageBox.cfm, then drop it into “{railo-install}/lib/railo-server/context/library/tag/”.  This will allow it to be recognized as a core tag and referenced via “”, which saves us from updating hundreds of templates that call it.  This, of course, requires us to create a message box custom tag from the ground up.
2. **cfDiv:**
   cfDiv seems to be throwing a JS error when used to bind to a JS function.  I'm going to guess that this is because JS binding is not officially supported (given that I can't find any reference in the official docs), and while ACF allows it as delayed execution, Railo simply doesn’t accept it.  We could just create a custom tag that generates a JS setTimeout as described in (1) above, which solved our problem, but applications that actually use this tag for its intended purpose may have a more difficult road ahead.
3. **cfWindow:**
   There appears to be limited support for cfWindow in Railo.  Specifically, new windows need manually shown, and the destroy methods do not exist.  Various other bugs appeared as well.  We decided that it made more sense to just move to JQuery based modals.
4. **cfLayout:**
   cfLayout support is questionable.  It is based on JQuery and not Ext-JS like ACF’s version.  This causes a problem because we run JQuery 1.10 right now and the built-in tag doesn’t appear to work beyond JQuery 1.8.  In fact, I could not find any JQuery version within which the tag worked perfectly.  We decided that it may be best to, again, just write our own custom tag based on JQuery.
5. **cfDocument:**
   cfDocument works differently in Railo and seems to require more strict HTML.  I found a lot of helpful information [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/lSPw6cctSUE), though as of yet I haven't actually gotten any of my cfDocument calls to work as expected.
6. **Relative cfLocations:**
   cfLocations that began with a “../” and backtracked beyond the webroot would throw a weird Java error.  This ended up being a bug in Tomcat, and was patched by the Railo team in version 4.3.1.003.  If you download an older Railo version you may run into this issue and need to update all of your cfLocation calls.
7. **Oracle Thin Client:**
   Our database guy reported to me that he setup the Oracle Thin Client, because the OCI client is not natively supported in Railo.  I found [this](http://bill.butler.net/2009/05/oracle-running-under-railo.html), which might be relevant, but I don't have the expertise to say for sure.
8. **Documentation:**
   ACF Livedocs are sometimes aggravating as they don't touch on the more important intricacies of how some tags are implemented, but Railo's version is the definition of minimalist.  I think it's fair to say that Railo has no docs specifying each tag and function and that they leave you to rely on Adobe for that, which causes a serious issue when you need to know how the two implementations differ.

In the end it seems like, as predicted by previous answers, the UI tags were the bulk of our issues.  Based on previous comments I was hoping for better implementations of them that may just require a tweak here and there, but (at least for our needs) the Railo versions seem borderline non-functional and it looks like we would need to replace them completely.  For us, this may not be realistic, though we are still tossing the idea around.

To be fair, here are some of the good points from our research and testing:

1. **Performance:**
   Although compatibility problems have prevented me from doing much performance testing, initial spot checks show approximately a 50% decrease in execution time for most pages.
2. **Debugging:**
   The debugging options in Railo are quite amazing.  There are far more options for formatting, including specifying different formats for different developers (IP addresses).  One incredible feature is the inclusion of a comma delimited list of query fields that were actually used in the page: this could allow you to effectively develop based on a "select *" query and simply copy and paste the fieldlist into the query at the end of development, which would save a lot of time with views as large as the ones we're using.
3. **Cost:**
   This is one of the larger reasons we decided to look into alternatives.  Switching just a few Enterprise licensed ACF servers over to Railo would save $20k+ over upgrading to the newest version of ACF.  Further, with the performance increases you could see an even greater savings in hardware requirements.  A side effect of this point is that one can keep far more up to date without the constant cost/benefit analysis of licensing costs holding up upgrades.
4. **Support:**
   Without a support contract, it doesn't seem like Adobe responds to user concerns.  I've had a production impacting bug reported since ACF 9 which still hasn't been fixed.  Yet the Railo community is one of the most helpful and responsive I've ever seen, and developers have even responded directly to concerns and bug reports I've raised.
5. **Longevity:**
   This is a highly opinionated point, of course, but while Adobe seems to be relegating ACF to the shadows more and more with each new version, Railo appears to be dedicated to growing the community.  Combined with its open source nature I think this makes it a safer bet for future support in the long term, even if that support is just us taking development into our own hands when needed.

For a number of reasons, including divergent CFML compatibility, we did not even get to the testing stage with Blue Dragon.

Comment: Yes, if you rely heavily on the UI tags then you're ... well, you're hosed, but as you can see from efforts like ColdFusion UI The Right Way, there are some fairly high-profile people in the community who will tell you that those UI tags are and always were a terrible idea. The Oracle Thin Client driver should be no problem: it's just JDBC in theory. I agree with your "pros" for what it is worth.

Comment: Speaking of Oracle: Not sure about the new versions, but back in the old Railo 3.x days Railo had an interesting bug, which made it impossible to just use a sequence to retrieve the inserted primary key of a newly inserted record: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-226

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on your code and the specific Adobe ColdFusion functionality that you are using. For the most part each CFML iteration supports the same tags/functionality. Where they deviate from the Adobe product is usually documented and explained. You need to dive into your code base and look specifically at the features you are using and compare those to the CFML engine of your choosing. Or you can just download and spin-up the alternate CFML engine, drop your code base in it and see what breaks.

As an example from Railo - [CFML Compatibility](http://www.getrailo.org/railoorg/index.cfm/documentation/compatibility/cfml-compatibility/)

> Railo tries to adhere the CFML standard as good as possible, Still there are some differences like missing tags and functions or a slightly different behavior. This page and the ones below should describe the incompatibilities.

And I have to question what you are basing this comment on?  "*and especially it's very uncertain future with them*".  You are running ColdFusion 9. Adobe has implemented two major version releases since then (10 and 11) and are currently working on the future release.

Comment: Thank you.  Perhaps my 'uncertain future' comment was more opinion based.  We've found CF developers harder and harder to find around here.  Adobe move CF to a small text link on their home page, and then relegated it to a minor page altogether.  Local user groups and gatherings have dried up.  It just seems that the community is shrinking and Adobe isn't focused on really marketing CF to rebuild that community.

Comment: I will probably try to drop our codebase into a Railo install to see what breaks once we can find a server for it.

Comment: I do agree with you that Adobe does a terrible job (none at all) of marketing CF.

Comment: I have rewritten my three comments (one on the question, two on this answer), as a separate more detailed answer - and deleted my comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main areas that can prove problematic when migrating from Adobe ColdFusion to Railo:

- Use of feature areas that are not supported by Railo
- Sloppy CFML code

The former includes integration with Microsoft technologies, such as Exchange and Sharepoint, as well as Office document manipulation; PDF forms and some of the more sophisticated document manipulations; UI "widget" integration. There are third party extensions for some of the Microsoft integrations, e.g., [cfSpreadsheet](https://github.com/teamcfadvance/cfspreadsheet-railo), but for PDF-related stuff you'll need to roll your own using Java libraries (PDF forms and high quality HTML to PDF conversion are Adobe specialties so be prepared to do quite a bit of work in your migration if you rely on these). As for the UI "widgets", you're better off doing that the "right way" so if you rely on those, you should [read ColdFusion UI The Right Way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way).

The latter is a harder issue to nail down. The differences are not well documented - except in experience posts to mailing lists and blogs by people who've made the transition to Railo - but they include things like:

- Using scope names as variables (Railo treats scopes as reserved names for performance reasons)
- Embedding comments inside tags, e.g., `<cfif x gt y <!--- check boundary --->>` (I've seen things like this in older CFML code and was surprised it worked).
- Reliance on automatic creation of nested struct elements, e.g., `a.b.c = 0` when `a` has not been declared.
- Reliance on long-deprecated features, e.g., `parameterExists()`.

There are many other small differences: Railo is generally stricter about syntax and semantics than Adobe ColdFusion, and often those decisions are driven by performance concerns in that compatibility with Adobe ColdFusion would make Railo slower.

Full disclosure here: I have used Railo pretty much exclusively for five years and I used to run the US arm of Railo's consulting business. That said, you need to consider that Railo is a small company (despite the backing of five fairly large former Adobe partners) with just a handful of people working on the engine, and very little awareness of the product outside the more leading edge portion of the CFML community. By comparison, Adobe have a large team and a marketing budget. Your concerns about the difficulty of finding developers will not be addressed by switching to Railo - to gain access to a larger developer pool, you'd really need to switch to a more popular language, not just a different engine.

Finally, a word about Blue Dragon's engine, specifically Open BlueDragon: the maintainers of that project have stated publicly several times that compatibility with the other engines (Adobe, Railo) is not a primary concern for them, and indeed there are a lot of modern language features that they still don't support or at least don't support in a compatible manner. Last I checked, full-script components were on that list despite having been supported in Adobe ColdFusion and Railo for many years (by which I mean using `component { ... }` rather than the `<cfcomponent><cfscript> .. </cfscript></cfcomponent>` form). The BlueDragon dialect of CFML has been steadily diverging over the years so unless you have very old school CFML, that would still run on CFMX7 / ACF8, you probably won't have much success trying to migrate to Open BlueDragon.